# Dynamically rendering objects from API in Javascript(object/API/dynamic rendering)

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object, dynamic

I have an array and objects in it, brought with the help of API. And If I enter name of an object to input it have to find that object and render its other properties to specific tags of HTML which are **located** in the **same** **container** with my **input** I entered name.
Actually this should have done in **Javascript**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to find an object by its name, you can use arr.filter():

```js
var desiredName = "Name 1" //The name entered into the input
const objects = [{name: "Name 1", name: "Name 2"}] //Your array of objects

//Use arr.filter() to find the item with the desired name
var selectedObject = objects.filter((item) => {
  return item.name = desiredName
})[0] //Target the first element in the returned array
```

As far as populating paragraph elements with the selected objects properties, you can just use document.getEleemntById():

```js
document.getElementById("someElement").innerHTML = "Your Text"
```

```html
<p id="someElement"></p>
```

Comment: Okay, how can i find the container that my input located because there are so many same containers all of them are same because they are dynamically rendered using a template.

Comment: What framework are you using? If you are just using vanilla HTML/JS, then you can use the onChange event listener on the input to run a function when it is typed into, or you can give the input an id to allow you to get its value when a button is pressed. I can go into more detail if this is the route you would like to go.